# How to draw patches situated in crossroads?

Tags: netlogo

How can I draw in red the patches situated in crossroads (the roads are drawn in white) as in the figure below ?

Here is my beginning of code:

```
ask patches with [ (pcolor = white) and (pxcor mod (nb-patch-length + 1) = 0 ) and (pycor mod (nb-patch-width + 1) = 0 ) ] [set pcolor red]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: You can get the red patches using `patches with [ pcolor = red ]`... but what do you want to "draw" in them?

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your answer. In fact, I would like to retrieve the white patches that are situated at the intersection between each white roads and at proximity of other coloured patches (e.g. green in the figure). Then these patches are coloured in red (as in the figure). Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?  (Assuming roads are one patch in width and are always horizontal or vertical.)

```
ask patches with [all? neighbors4 [pcolor = white]] [set pcolor red]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Allan for your answer. This codes find the patches situated at the intersection between each white roads, but does not find the patches situated at the edge of other coloured patches.Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You'll probably want to do those separately.  E.g., `ask patches with [(pcolor = white) and (any? neighbors4 with [pcolor = green])] [set pcolor red]`.